# how to describe a decrease in sales

Tags: data-analysis, marketing, glm

Hypothetically, if your company's sales had dropped significantly in 2020, what approach would you take to describe the cause? can you build a model to predict the decrease (between 2019 and 2020 for example) to visualize what the leading indicators are?

Comment: 2020 may not be a very good year for doing data, as the pandemic may have induced very out-of-distribution behavior.

Comment: it doesnt have to be 2020 Im just saying that I want to know how I could describe changes.

Comment: Fall in sales could occur due to less advertising expenses or new products introduced by competitors or decrease in Salesforce..

Comment: how can I quantify the causes given you have data to work with. Idealy in the form of 40% due to X, 30% due to Y, etc.